# C style array with C++?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I have read many answers on stackoverflow and codereview that says we should not use C style arrays with C++. What is reason for it ?
If I use std::Array instead of C style array, will it impact on speed/performance ?

In my organization, entire application is written in C++. But only C style arrays are used.

Comment: Theoretically there's no penalty using `std::array` over a C-style array, and practically I doubt it as well (as long as you don't pass the array *by value*, which is possible with `std::array` but not with a C-style array).

Comment: Glad to see my gold "arrays" badge getting some use 

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude In C I can create variable length array at runtime like `int arr[n]`. Is it possible with std::array ?

Comment: @KamalPancholi VLAs are not allowed in standard C++.

Comment: @KamalPancholi For that you have `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not have impact on performance. There are two reasons to use std::array instead C-like arrays:

- Method at() that allows to get an element by index with bounds checking. Beware, operator [] doesn't have bounds checking.
- Limited pointer arithmetic. It's much harder to shoot in the foot than with C-like arrays.
- Same behavior as other std containers, like begin(), end(), size() methods without necessity to handle two variables: pointer and size. So, you can implement one algorithm that can work with arrays and other containers.

Thanks Thomas Sablik for clarification in comments.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Yes, but the problem with simple C-style arrays is that they too often decay to pointers, and then `std::begin()` and `std::end()` won't work very well.